# Referring to a the sub-type of a path-dependent type

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

The following works:

```
class Outter {
    type Inner = Either[Int,String]
    type L = Left[Int,String]
    type R = Right[Int,String]

    def f(x: Inner) = 1
  }

  val o = new Outter
  o.f(new o.L(1))
  o.f(new o.R("name"))
```

but only because there is an explicit `type` member for all the sub-types of the `Inner`. Is it possible to construct a value from a sub-type of a path-dependent type *without* the need to mention them explicitly in the `Outter` ? Like:

```
class Outter {
    type Inner = Either[Int,String]
    def f(x: Inner) = 1
  }

  val o = new Outter
  o.f(new o.?!?(1))  // How do I express "that particular Left[Int,String] which is the sub-type of o.Inner
  o.f(new o.?!?("name")) // same as above here, but for Right
```

Related [Path-dependent argument type is not enforced (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35557655/369489)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Inner = Either[Int, String]
```

This is a type alias. `Inner` is not a subclass of `Either[Int, String]` they are the same. Just syntactic sugar.
So you can stil refer to the subclasses of `Either[Int, String]` as if they are subclasses of `Inner`

So the solution might be more straightforward then you imagined.

```
val o = new Outter
o.f(Left(1)) // How do I express "that particular Left[Int,String] which is the sub-type of o.Inner
o.f(Right("name")) // same as above here, but for Right
```

Comment: "This is a type alias. `Either[Int, String]` is not a subclass of `Either`" yeah I know. That was not my question (by the way, `Either[Int,String]` is *not* the same as`Either`. The former is a proper type, the later is a type constructor of arity 2).

Comment: The question is, how do I create `Left` and `Right` of the expected type (which is `o.Inner` and *not* `Inner`). I don't have a REPL handy but I think your code does not type check (type mismatch, required `o.Inner`, found `Left`)

Comment: "by the way, `Either[Int,String]` is not the same as `Either`". This is a typo on my part. I meant to say "`Inner` is not a subclass of `Either[Int, String]`". I edited my answer.

Comment: Apparently you are right ! I'll experiment a lilbit and I'll get back

Comment: Kindly see the related question (I added it at the end of this one)