# Path-dependent argument type is not enforced (?)

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

```
class Outter {
  type Inner = Either[Int, String]

  def f(x: this.Inner) = 1
}

val o = new Outter
val someLeft = Left(1)
o.f(someLeft)
```

tried at the REPL:

```
scala> :load Learn.scala
Loading Learn.scala...
defined class Outter
o: Outter = Outter@28037ced
someLeft: scala.util.Left[Int,Nothing] = Left(1)
res0: Int = 1
```

Which confuses the hell out of me as `Outter.f()` has an explicit path-dependent type argument (`x: this.Inner`) which means *only* those `Left`s (or `Right`s) that are (a sub-type of) `o.Inner` are allowed and *not* just any `Left[Int,_]` or `Right[Int,_]`. I expect to see a type mismatch error along the lines :

Required `o.Inner`, Found `Left[Int,Nothing]`.

But it just compiles fine! What am I (badly) missing here ?

Comment: Also, see the (original) related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35542846/369489

Comment: Also also, see the follow-up http://stackoverflow.com/q/35558342/369489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type Inner = Either[Int, String]` is just a type alias. This is the expected behavior.

> only those Lefts (or Rights) that are (a sub-type of) `o.Inner` are allowed and not just any `Left[Int, _]` or `Right[Int, _]`.

There is only one `Left` and one `Right` class, respectively. There are no `Left`s or `Right`s that are *only* a sub-type of `o.Inner` and nothing else. Creating a type alias does not create a new type that belongs only to class `Outter`. The only thing that is unique to `Outter` is the alias name `Inner`, but `Either` is the same old `scala.util.Either`.

Comment: Then there is no way of creating path-dependent types from the types already defined ?

Comment: I believe I'm severely off the charts here :D

Comment: Not exactly. You might try wrapping the types, instead? I'm not sure why you'd want something like this.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `type` alias would spare me the hassle of (re)implementing an `Either` that depends on the enclosing value (i.e. path-dependent). Now I understand `type` is just an alias = nothing to do with the enclosing object. How do I achieve the "wrapping" then ? as `Either` is sealed ...

Comment: Why not create a case class containing the either `case class Inner(inner: Either[Int, String])`

Comment: The first answer here looks like something you could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types

Comment: @m-z and Pim (apparently can't @-mention you :( ) , kindly take a look at follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35558342/369489

Comment: @PimVerkerk yeah I have been through that already. Many times, actually. But apparently there is something big I have managed to miss here :-). Take a look at my follow-up though. That's what I'm trying to achieve here.